# How to deal with Epipole inside Image (Stereo image) and Persistance of Outlier

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, stereo-3d, matlab-cvst

I am using Matlab to create a stereo image.  I have followed the example shown here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-image-rectification.html

The "if" loop is where I hit problems:

```
if status ~= 0 || isEpipoleInImage(fMatrix, size(I1)) ...
  || isEpipoleInImage(fMatrix', size(I2))
  error(['Either not enough matching points were found or '...
     'the epipoles are inside the images. You may need to '...
    'inspect and improve the quality of detected features ',...
    'and/or improve the quality of your images.']);
```

I've commented out the status part so I know that there is an epipole within an image.  I'm not sure what sort of problem this creates.  Is it a big issue, or should I just comment this part out?  Also, things look good for the most part but an outlier persists after the RANSAC implementation - any help with fixing that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You can put a `keyboard`instead of the `error(...)` into the `if` clause, and then inspect the variables status, fMatrix, etc, one by one from the console to see where exactly the error is coming from.

Comment: Thank you Martin, I'll try this out.  Any ideas for the outlier?

Answer (score 1):

for getting rid of outliers, there are 2 things you can do.

1) Change the threshold of the feature detector

2) Modify some parts of RANSAC, such as minimum number of inliers for termination and minimum acceptable error in homography